# Use puppeteer to break a section of text into array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to **scrape** a `<section>` of text. The section contains headings that you can identify by the bold tag, `<b>`, and the text underneath the bold tag is the content of the heading.

This is what the section of HTML looks like:

**Example**

```
<section class="description">
  <div>
    <b>Heading 1 <br /></b>
    This is content related to heading 1.
    <br />
    <b>Heading 2 <br /></b>
    This is content related to heading 2.
    <br />
  </div>
</section>
```

How do you break this up into an array of objects that might look like;

```
const section = [
  {
    heading: "Heading text",
    content: "This is the text that relates to the heading."
  }
];
```

Right now the only thing I can do is grab the inner text using.

```
await page.evaluate(
  () => document.querySelector("section.job-description").textContent
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to find all `<b>` tags within `.description` then use [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) to select the adjacent text node.

This relies heavily on there being no other elements between the `<b>...</b>` and the text.

Example...

```js
const section = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.description b'), b => ({
  heading: b.textContent.trim(),
  content: b.nextSibling.textContent.trim()
}))

console.info(section)
```

```html
<section class="description">
  <div>
    <b>Heading 1 <br /></b>
    This is content related to heading 1.
    <br />
    <b>Heading 2 <br /></b>
    This is content related to heading 2.
    <br />
  </div>
</section>
```